# How to compare list of objects and keep only _new_ objects?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, diff, deep-diff

I have two JSON files named `new` and `old` that files have some data. here I want to compare `new.json` with the `old.json` file while comparing if I have the same data in those two JSON files I don't want to create any new JSON file

If I have different data like below in `new.json` and `old.json`

`new.json`:

```
[
 {
    "name": "Mohan raj",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Kiruthika",
    "age": 18,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Munusamy",
    "age": 45,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "USA"
 }
]
```

`old.json`:

```
[
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Oscar Bernard",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "Australia"
 }
]
```

If the `new.json` file has any of the same data of `old.json` having we have to skip that data and the `new.json` file have any of the updated data of `old.json` having and the new data's in `new.json` we have to create a new JSON file named `updated.json` with the data of the above scenarios.

The resulted JSON file needs to look like this:

`updated.json`:

```
[
 {
    "name": "Mohan raj",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Kiruthika",
    "age": 18,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Munusamy",
    "age": 45,
    "country": "INDIA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "USA"
 }
]
```

Comment: what happend to ```{
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 }```

Comment: @shivankgtm if the data is same we can skip that

Comment: ohh acha, you want to have only those which are not in old.json.

Comment: @shivankgtm yes bro

Comment: What if the same records just change position in the list?

Comment: @ZachYoung if same records occurs we have to skip that

Comment: And you want to evaluate same-or-different based on `name`?

Comment: @ZachYoung not only based on name. that;s bassed on all the data in that dict

Comment: Got, it, thanks. I'm pretty sure I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to get, thanks for answering my questions, and it seems like "updated" might simply be expressed as "new not in old"?

I think so, because the following seems to do the job.

The key is to make comparisons of the objects themselves, and not wanting to get into object comparison (deep-equal), just *hashing* each object back to JSON gives us string representations we can compare:

```py
import json

old_hashes = []

old_objs = json.load(open('old.json'))
for old_obj in old_objs:
    old_hash = json.dumps(old_obj)
    old_hashes.append(old_hash)


# "Updated" means "new not in old"
updated_objs = []

new_objs = json.load(open('new.json'))
for new_obj in new_objs:
    new_hash = json.dumps(new_obj)
    if new_hash not in old_hashes:
        updated_objs.append(new_obj)


print(json.dumps(updated_objs, indent=2))
```

When I run that against your **old.json** and **new.json**, I get:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Mohan raj",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "INDIA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kiruthika",
    "age": 18,
    "country": "INDIA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Munusamy",
    "age": 45,
    "country": "INDIA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "USA"
  }
]
```

Comment: I also need to write this as a new file

Comment: Does the algorithm work? Do I understand the problem and did I present a _workable_ solution? You can check out the docs on reading and [writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) JSON.

Comment: No, I cannot; and that's not why I answered this question. I'm trying to _help you_ solve a problem, not write complete coded solutions for you. That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: The Algorithm is working but if this is in OOP Structure that will be useful for me very much..

Comment: Then you should accept this answer, because it satisfies the question you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it below. keep track of data from old json.

```
import json

# read json file
with open('new.json') as f:
    new_data = json.load(f)
with open('old.json') as f:
    old_data = json.load(f)

old_json_list = [
    {elem["name"], elem["age"], elem["country"]} for elem in old_data]
    
updated_list = []
for elem in new_data:
    elm = {elem["name"], elem["age"], elem["country"]}
    if elm not in old_json_list:
        updated_list.append(elem)

with open('updated.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(updated_list, f)
```

Comment: I need to change the key's value at runtime.
i want to use this process for different type of json files

Comment: Need to change the keys values? Can you elaborate